# Custom Maven plugin - get all XML files from src/test/resources folder

Tags: maven, plugins

I try to process all XML files of a Maven project using a custom Maven plugin.
Is it possible to get all the XML files from the project's **src/test/resources**?

SK

Comment: The simple answer to your question is: "Yes" ..but to be honest this can't be the answer cause you have given not very much information what you did what you've already tried and what exactly you are trying to achieve? And what kind of custom Maven Plugin for what purpose ?

Comment: My intention is to find out if each JAVA class has a corresponding XML file or not. The XML file's path and name is (should be) like JAVA class's package and name.